# Console.log Input with first letter capitalized

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

Started a bootcamp at one of our first tasks is to write a simple program that asks for the users input and logs it to the console.
My code is working but the last subtask isn´t working.
When the browser open the window a pop up shows up with the question what is your name.
You enter your name and it will get logged to the console. If you don´t enter anything the Console logs Hello World!.
All that is working fine, last subtask is to capitalize the first letter of the users input.
I looked up how to do that and found an example with charAt(0) + string.slice(1) and try to used it in my code.
I tried it on every variable that is read but it doesn´t work, what perplexes me the most is that my code still runs and reads your input.
I could really use some help here.
I will of course provide the code.

```js
// Write your JavaScript code here
function getUserName(){
    let nameInput = prompt("What is your name?");
    return nameInput;
}

function getHelloMessage(){
    if(nameInput === ""){
        nameInput = "World"
    }
    return "Hello " + nameInput + " !";
}

function sayHello() {
    let messageOutputed = getHelloMessage();
    let newMessage = messageOutputed.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + messageOutputed.slice(1);
    console.log(messageOutputed);
};
sayHello();
```

Thanks for your help people.

Comment: you say your code is asking for user name, but you never called `getUserName()` anywhere. If you add this line `let nameInput = getUserName();` before saying hello, it should work. As a side  note, the variable declared inside a function will be in that scope and won't be available outside the function

Comment: and to comment on your strategy, you are processing the whole message when switching the first letter to uppercase instead of targeting the name alone. So actually you are transforming `Hello` and not the first letter of the name

Comment: please don't use regex for this .. it's way overkill. You just need to capitalize the first letter and you don't need to match any pattern

Comment: I used your way and it now works had to add some parameters and added some new variables but it works, thanks for the help ya all.

Answer (score 0):

For capitalizing you can use regex also
and I think this code can help you and solve your problem

```
// Write your JavaScript code here
function getUserName(){
    let nameInput = prompt("What is your name?");
    return nameInput;
}

function getHelloMessage(){
  let nameInput = getUserName();
    if(nameInput === ""){
        nameInput = "World"
    }
    return "Hello " + nameInput + " !";
}

function _capitalizeWord(word) {
  return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
}

function sayHello() {
    let messageOutputed = getHelloMessage().match(/[A-Za-z][a-z]*/g) || [];
    let newMessage = messageOutputed.map(this._capitalizeWord).join(' ');
    console.log(newMessage);
};

sayHello();
```

Comment: We don´t use regex and it seems pretty difficult for a beginner with no experience but thanks either way. I will look into regex.

Comment: Instead of using regex you can try this `let messageOutputed = getHelloMessage().split(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want output captalize text in console output.

No need to use extra js.
Tested in firefox console and chrome

```
console.log("%chello world", "text-transform: capitalize;");
```